# Harvesting multiple files with one C# COM dll

Tags: msbuild, wix, heat

I'm compiling a WiX installer and using Heat to harvest my files but I'm running into a problem where I have a directory I'm harvesting that contains 1 C# COM dll.  I need to basically run regasm on this.  I have the following in my wix project file to harvest the files:

```
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="%(ProjectReference.Filename).wxs" 
               Directory="..\ExactaMobilePublish\" 
               DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" 
               ComponentGroupName="%(ProjectReference.Filename)" 
               SuppressUniqueIds="true" 
               SuppressCom="false" 
               SuppressFragments="true" 
               SuppressRegistry="false" 
               SuppressRootDirectory="true" 
               AutoGenerateGuids="false" 
               GenerateGuidsNow="true" 
               ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" 
               PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath" />
```

The problem I'm having is that while it is generating the necessary registry information for my C# COM dll it's also generating registry information for a bunch of other dlls in that folder that aren't exposed to COM.

Is there any way around this?  Should I instead try harvesting that single C# COM dll into a separate wxs file?

#### Edit

I did try harvesting the single C# COM dll in a seperate WiX file in addition to the directory defined above but I got the expected error:

```
Error   5   Duplicate symbol 'Component:ExactaDatabaseAccess.dll' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.  C:\TFS\Covance\Dev\ExactaMobileCNA317\Installer\ExactaMobileInstaller\ExactaMobile.wxs  143 1   ExactaMobileInstaller
```

I could probably exclude this file from the directory above by using an xslt transform but this seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by doing as I had suggested in the edit above.  I harvested the single file using `HeatFile` and excluded the file from the `HeatDirectory` harvest by using an xslt transform.

I had the following in my project file:

```
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="%(ProjectReference.Filename).wxs" 
               Directory="..\ExactaMobilePublish\" 
               DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" 
               Transforms="ExcludeExactaDatabaseAccess.xslt" 
               ComponentGroupName="%(ProjectReference.Filename)" 
               SuppressUniqueIds="true" 
               SuppressCom="true" 
               SuppressFragments="true" 
               SuppressRegistry="true" 
               SuppressRootDirectory="true" 
               AutoGenerateGuids="false" 
               GenerateGuidsNow="true" 
               ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" 
               PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath" />
<HeatFile OutputFile="ExactaDatabaseAccess.wxs" 
          File="..\ExactaMobilePublish\bin\ExactaDatabaseAccess.dll" 
          DirectoryRefId="MOBILEBIN" 
          ComponentGroupName="ExactaDatabaseAccess" 
          SuppressUniqueIds="true" 
          SuppressCom="false" 
          SuppressFragments="true" 
          SuppressRegistry="false" 
          SuppressRootDirectory="true" 
          AutoGenerateGuids="false" 
          GenerateGuidsNow="true" 
          ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" 
          PreprocessorVariable="var.ExactaMobileBinBasePath" />
```

I used the following xslt transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
      xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Search directories for the components that will be removed. -->
  <xsl:key name="dll-search" match="wix:Component[@Id = 'ExactaDatabaseAccess.dll']" use="descendant::wix:File/@Id"/>

  <!-- Remove components. -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[@Id='ExactaDatabaseAccess.dll']" />

  <!-- Remove componentsrefs referencing components in those directories. -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('dll-search', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```